# Unibody off-road vehicle with differential locks and reduction

Tags: body, 4wd, awd, frame

I want to create a list of current off-road vehicles (say in production during last 10 years) that have unibody construction (as opposed to body on-frame) but still have most off-road features like manual differential locks (front, center or rear) or gearbox reduction.

So far I know about these vehicles:

- Volkswagen Touareg Mk1 (2002-2010) - center, front and rear diff lock
- Suzuki Vitara - Mk3 (2005-) and Mk4 (2015-) - only center lock?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking about model features rather than maintenance or repair.

Comment: And it is quite easy to find a list of suitable vehicles given the info available - just basic research.